# Vue js Keeping track of selected checkboxes in scoped slot

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a table where i am trying to add a checkbox control to each row via a slot. 
The problem is I cant figure how to record the selected items in the parent component when they are selected.... v-model doesnt seem to work.

I modified a codepen to show what im trying to achieve...

https://codesandbox.io/s/qkl5jm54w4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a simple naming mismatch.

In your App.vue, you have `v-model="selectedUsers"` on the checkbox, but

```
data() {
    return {
      selected: []
```

If you change it to `v-model="selected"`, everything seems to work.

Comment: thanks, here i was overthinking it and it was something so simple